# auto generate hyperlink column for c# gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

I have a query, output of which populates a gridview. The columns of gridview are not fixed, i.e except for 1st columns rest column count can vary.

Output table structure is roughly:

```
    name | week1 | week2
    stu1 | 23    | 0
    stu2 | 45    | 6
```

The column count varies because week no is not static.
Is it possible to generate hyperlink in the cells where cell value is greater than zero? And if possible then how to get the row and column index on clicking the digit and redirecting to another page for details?

Comment: show gridview code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in RowDataBound event , as given in msdn : [GridView.RowDataBound Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      for(var cell in e.Row.Cells)
      {
       int val = 0; 
       if(int.TryParse(cell.Text,out val)
       {
        //you can have hyper link here 
        if(val > 0)
        cell.Text = "<a href='void(0);'>" + cell.Text + "</a>";
       }
      } 

    }
  }
```

Comment: `e.Row.Cells[0].Add(new HyperLink(){ Text = "cell.Text"});`?

Comment: @Toshi - that yes agree but why to create new class ... it better jut to put html tag , so there is no object creation ...

Comment: What's so bad about a object ceration? It's rendered as `<a>` - This string concartenation way is like sql parameters - it leads to errors

Comment: @Toshi - yes but as developer you know here right that if its integer than you go in and do change ,,, but any way its all depends on developer preference ...if you like to create HyperLink than its your preference , i like a tag that is my preference